# How to search particular values in a datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

Guys I have a `datatable` in an ASP webforms application in which I am trying to implement a kind-of-sort. Basically I have two fields named `Agent_Name` & `Agent_Code` in my datatable.

For example `datatable` is having values like this :

```
+------------+------------+
| Agent_Code | Agent_Name |
+------------+------------+
|          1 | A          |
|          2 | B          |
|          3 | C          |
|          4 | D          |
|          5 | E          |
+------------+------------+
```

Now I have another array of `Agent_Code` in which I have `2,3,5` now I want to compare this array with the `datatable` and only keeps those records in `datatable` which have `Agent_Code` = `2,3,5` in them and discard the rest. So the final `datatable` will look like :

```
+------------+------------+
| Agent_Code | Agent_Name |
+------------+------------+
|          2 | B          |
|          3 | C          |
|          5 | E          |
+------------+------------+
```

How should I about doing this ? I will appreciate some pointers.

Note : Please suggest something other than linq, I am using webforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a nested for loop:

```
for (int y = OriginalDataTable.Rows.Count - 1; y >= 0; y--)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= AgentCodeArray.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (OriginalDataTable.Rows[y]["Agent_Code"].ToString() != AgentCodeArray[i].ToString())
        {
            count++;
            if (count == AgentCodeArray.Length)
                OriginalDataTable.Rows[y].Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

What this does is go through each record in the datatable and checks if "Agent_Code" is contained anywhere in the new array. If so, let it be. If not, delete it.

The key here being going backwards through the data table while deleting. If you don't, the indexes will get reordered and you would see an error.

Comment: Getting this error : 
`Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row.` on this loop `if (OriginalDataTable.Rows[y]["Agent_Code"].ToString() != AgentCodeArray[i].ToString())`

Comment: That error generally means you are trying to access a row that has been deleted. This implies that the row was deleted prematurely. I would first check to see the value of `count` and `AgentCodeArray.Length` are what they should be.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
//creating some test datatable and agent list
DataTable table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Agent_Code"));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Agent_Name"));

DataRow row1 = table.NewRow();
DataRow row2 = table.NewRow();
DataRow row3 = table.NewRow();
DataRow row4 = table.NewRow();
DataRow row5 = table.NewRow();

row1["Agent_Code"] = 1;
row2["Agent_Code"] = 2;
row3["Agent_Code"] = 3;
row4["Agent_Code"] = 4;
row5["Agent_Code"] = 5;

row1["Agent_Name"] = "A";
row2["Agent_Name"] = "B";
row3["Agent_Name"] = "C";
row4["Agent_Name"] = "D";
row5["Agent_Name"] = "E";

table.Rows.Add(row1);
table.Rows.Add(row2);
table.Rows.Add(row3);
table.Rows.Add(row4);
table.Rows.Add(row5);

string[] Agent_Code = new string[] { "1", "3" };

//finished test data

//actual logic here
StringBuilder filterBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < Agent_Code.Length; i++)
{
     if (i != 0) filterBuilder.Append(" OR ");

     filterBuilder.Append("Agent_Code = '");
     filterBuilder.Append(Agent_Code[i]);
     filterBuilder.Append("'");
}

DataView view = new DataView(table, filterBuilder.ToString(), "Agent_Code", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

DataTable newTable = view.ToTable();
```

Comment: I am using webforms, could you please suggest something other than linq?

Comment: Updated my answer although you can use LINQ anywhere unless your target framework is below version 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you

```
string[] single = new string[2] { "2", "3" };
var arr = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(r => single.Contains(r.Field<string>
                                     ("Agent_Code"))).CopyToDataTable();
```

In this example dt is your datasource which is get from gridview.datasource and single  is array of your Agent_Code.

Comment: I am not allowed to use linq.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using LINQ, as offered by Pragnesh, you may also consider creating a DataView.

Using the array data you have, loop through the DataView that contains the original set in the DataTable using the RowFilter property to remove the DataTable entries that don't match those in the array.

Sort the filtered results that are in the DataView, and you have your filtered and sorted set.